# Phoenix mix phx.gen.html generated bad links

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I used phx.gen.html to generate several controllers, templates, etc. and the templates contain code which constructions hyperlinks as follows.

```
<span><%= link "New Priority", to: priority_path(@conn, :new) %></span>
```

The link that this generates is plural, i.e. priorities, but the controller and other items are all singular, so the link doesn't work.

First, how can I affect the priority_path, and/or second, how do I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: What exact `mix` command have you used to generate stuff?

Comment: mix phx.gen.html Lookups Priority priorities name:string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not adding the route to your `router.ex` file.

```elixir
resources("/priorities", PriorityController)
```

or

```elixir
resources("/priority", PriorityController)
```

or

```elixir
get("/priority", PriorityController, :new)
```

should all work with `priority_path(@conn, :new)`

If you wanted to follow convention it would be the first example with a plural path and singular controller that you would use, but you can use whatever you like as long as the controller and path helper function match (`PriorityController` and `priority_path` vs `PrioritiesController` and `priorities_path`), since the path helper seems to be generated from the controller name.

Unless you use the `:as` option, which would look like:

```elixir
resources("/priorities", PrioritiesController, as: :priority)
```

would give you `priority_path` helper. Whereas

```elixir
resources("/priorities", PrioritiesController)
```

would give you `priorities_path` helper.

[The docs might help.](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#path-helpers)

Comment: I actually found this as a possible solution and added it to my router.ex file, but that did not fix the problem. Does that have to be in there when you do the generation, or does it matter where this is added?

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. it does not matter when it is added, but it must be there when you run your application and you must recompile (e.g. if phoenix is running in dev mode it will not get changes to the router).

Comment: I had added a conflicting code, and I needed to put the resources inside the scope "/" .  Thanks very much!!!